# NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x000000063069d8>

Tags: ruby, http

Estou fazendo uma requisição REST mas ao executar tenho este erro:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x000000063069d8>
```

Meu codigo:

```
  require 'net/http'


require 'uri'


def mandareq

  url = URI("https://gateway.plusmms.net/rest/message?")

  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)

  request.body = {to:[number],text:'teste',from:'Remetente'}


  response = http.request(request)
  puts response.read_body

end
```

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, foi so adicionar o seguinte código:

```
  http.use_ssl = true
```

Abaixo desta linha :

```
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
```